# I have two dropdown menu. One horizontal and one vertical. I want them in one page, but it does not work together

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is the side menu:

```css
/*Set the parent <li>’s CSS position property to ‘relative’.*/

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
 float: right;
}
ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -200px;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
li ul {
 margin-top: -50px;
 display:none;
}
ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
.main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
ul ul ul {
 margin-left: -120px;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-us">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>oldal.menu</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="side.menu2.css"
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="menu">
      <ul>
    <li><a>Közérdekű adatok</a></li>
    <li><a>Járóbeteg szakellátó</a></li>
    <li><a>Álláslehetőségek</a></li>
    <li><a>Közszolgálati intézmények</a></li>
    <li><a>Civil szervezetek</a></li>
    <li><a>Egyházak</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Református egyház</a></li>
      <li><a>Katolikus egyház</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Idegenforgalom</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Térkép</a></li>
      <li><a>Vadászat</a></li>
      <li><a>Horgászat</a></li>
      <li><a>Túrázás</a></li>
      <li><a>Szálláslehetőségek</a></li>
      <li><a>Kultúrális rendezvények</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Galéria</a></li>
    <li><a>Kiadványok</a></li>
    <li><a>Cigándi hírmondó</a></li>
    <li><a>Árapasztó tározó</a></li>
    <li><a>Gazdahírek</a></li>
    <li><a>Archívum</a></li>
    <li><a>Eladó ingatlanok</a></li>
    <li><a>Hasznos linkek</a></li>
    <li><a>Kistérség</a></li>
    <li><a>Magyar Államkincstár</a></li>
    <li><a>TÁMOP-3.2.3/A-11/1-2012-0112</a></li>
    <li><a>Cigándi Járási Hivatal</a></li>
    <li><a>ITS projekt</a></li>
    <li><a>Település üzemeltetés</a></li>
    <li><a>Művészeti csoportok</a></li>
    <li><a>ÁNYK nyomtatványok</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

And now I insert the horizontal menu:

```css
/*Set the parent <li>â€™s CSS position property to â€˜relativeâ€™.*/

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
li ul {
 display:none;
}
ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
.main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

#main-navigation {
 width: 100%;
}
#main-navigation ul:before,
#main-navigation ul:after {
 content: '';
 display:table;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu-hu">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>cigand.menu.nested.list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
     type="text/css"
          href="cigand.hu.menu.2.css" />
     
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main-navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a>Városunk</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Köszöntő</a></li>
     <li><a>Földrajz</a></li>
     <li><a>Története</a></li>
     <li><a>Heraldika</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Önkormányzat</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Polgármesteri Hivatal</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Polgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Alpolgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Jegyző</a></li>
       <li><a>Titkárság</a></li>
       <li><a>Hatósági és Igazgatási Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Építésügyi és Városfejlesztési Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Pénzügyi Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Letölthető dokumentumok</a></li>
       <li><a>Pályázatok</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>EU</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP</a></li>
         <li><a>TIOP-1.2.3</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.1.0/A/11.</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0121</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0124</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-4.2.0/A/11-2011-0626</a></li>
         <li><a>EOP-5.5.0/K/14-2014-0031</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP-1.A.3-2014-2014-0116</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-5.7.0/15-2015-0275</a></li>
         <li><a>KÖFOP-1.2.1-VEKOP-16-2016-00280</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Képviselő-testület</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Képviselők</a></li>
       <li><a>Határozatok, Rendeletek</a></li>
       <li><a>Rendelet-tervezetek</a></li>
       <li><a>estületi ülések</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>RNÖ</a></li>
     <li><a>Telefonszámok</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Oktatás és Kultúra</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Oktatás</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Cigánd</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Óvoda</a></li>
         <li><a>Iskola</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Révleányvár</a></li>
       <li><a>Zemplénagárd</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Kultúra</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Művelődési Ház</a></li>
       <li><a>Városi Könyvtár</a></li>
       <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Iskolakonyha</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Egészségügy</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Háziorvosok</a></li>
     <li><a>Fogorvos</a></li>
     <li><a>Központi Orvosi Ügyelet</a></li>
     <li><a>Védőnői Szolgálat</a></li>
     <li><a>Járóbeteg Szakrendelő</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Hagyományok</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
     <li><a>Tájház</a></li>
     <li><a>Óvodamúzeum</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Sport</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Intézmények</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Szabadidő Központ</a></li>
       <li><a>Műfüves-pálya</a></li>
       <li><a>Labdarúgó-pálya</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Cigánd SE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Kezdőlap</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

So how to modify the code to put every menu in one page. I know the result is easy but my work is not working. I added unique name to all "ul" "li" and "a" but it did not work. The CSS file needs some modification.
```

So how to modify the code to put every menu in one page. I know the result is easy but my work is not working. I added unique name to all "ul" "li" and "a" but it did not work. The CSS file needs some modification.

Comment: Have you tried using the burger icon for the side navigation menu. I assume you don't want both menu's to be visible simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Your css is correct. you just need to add ID before your css like below. please add id in all css property.

```
#main-navigation ul
#menu ul
```

Also you can check on snippet.

```css
/*Set the parent <li>â€™s CSS position property to â€˜relativeâ€™.*/

#main-navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
#main-navigation ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
#main-navigation ul li ul {
 display:none;
}
#main-navigation ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
#main-navigation ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
#main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
#main-navigation ul li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
#main-navigation ul li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
#main-navigation ul li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
#main-navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
#main-navigation ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

#main-navigation {
 width: 100%;
}
#main-navigation ul:before,
#main-navigation ul:after {
 content: '';
 display:table;
 clear: both;
}


/*Set the parent <li>’s CSS position property to ‘relative’.*/

#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
 float: right;
}
#menu ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -200px;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
#menu li ul {
 margin-top: -50px;
 display:none;
}
#menu ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
#menu li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
#menu li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
#menu li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
#menu li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
#menu .main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
#menu ul ul ul {
 margin-left: -120px;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a>Városunk</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Köszöntő</a></li>
     <li><a>Földrajz</a></li>
     <li><a>Története</a></li>
     <li><a>Heraldika</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Önkormányzat</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Polgármesteri Hivatal</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Polgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Alpolgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Jegyző</a></li>
       <li><a>Titkárság</a></li>
       <li><a>Hatósági és Igazgatási Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Építésügyi és Városfejlesztési Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Pénzügyi Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Letölthető dokumentumok</a></li>
       <li><a>Pályázatok</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>EU</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP</a></li>
         <li><a>TIOP-1.2.3</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.1.0/A/11.</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0121</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0124</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-4.2.0/A/11-2011-0626</a></li>
         <li><a>EOP-5.5.0/K/14-2014-0031</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP-1.A.3-2014-2014-0116</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-5.7.0/15-2015-0275</a></li>
         <li><a>KÖFOP-1.2.1-VEKOP-16-2016-00280</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Képviselő-testület</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Képviselők</a></li>
       <li><a>Határozatok, Rendeletek</a></li>
       <li><a>Rendelet-tervezetek</a></li>
       <li><a>estületi ülések</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>RNÖ</a></li>
     <li><a>Telefonszámok</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Oktatás és Kultúra</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Oktatás</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Cigánd</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Óvoda</a></li>
         <li><a>Iskola</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Révleányvár</a></li>
       <li><a>Zemplénagárd</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Kultúra</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Művelődési Ház</a></li>
       <li><a>Városi Könyvtár</a></li>
       <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Iskolakonyha</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Egészségügy</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Háziorvosok</a></li>
     <li><a>Fogorvos</a></li>
     <li><a>Központi Orvosi Ügyelet</a></li>
     <li><a>Védőnői Szolgálat</a></li>
     <li><a>Járóbeteg Szakrendelő</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Hagyományok</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
     <li><a>Tájház</a></li>
     <li><a>Óvodamúzeum</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Sport</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Intézmények</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Szabadidő Központ</a></li>
       <li><a>Műfüves-pálya</a></li>
       <li><a>Labdarúgó-pálya</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Cigánd SE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Kezdőlap</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 
  <div id="menu">
      <ul>
    <li><a>Közérdekű adatok</a></li>
    <li><a>Járóbeteg szakellátó</a></li>
    <li><a>Álláslehetőségek</a></li>
    <li><a>Közszolgálati intézmények</a></li>
    <li><a>Civil szervezetek</a></li>
    <li><a>Egyházak</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Református egyház</a></li>
      <li><a>Katolikus egyház</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Idegenforgalom</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a>Térkép</a></li>
      <li><a>Vadászat</a></li>
      <li><a>Horgászat</a></li>
      <li><a>Túrázás</a></li>
      <li><a>Szálláslehetőségek</a></li>
      <li><a>Kultúrális rendezvények</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Galéria</a></li>
    <li><a>Kiadványok</a></li>
    <li><a>Cigándi hírmondó</a></li>
    <li><a>Árapasztó tározó</a></li>
    <li><a>Gazdahírek</a></li>
    <li><a>Archívum</a></li>
    <li><a>Eladó ingatlanok</a></li>
    <li><a>Hasznos linkek</a></li>
    <li><a>Kistérség</a></li>
    <li><a>Magyar Államkincstár</a></li>
    <li><a>TÁMOP-3.2.3/A-11/1-2012-0112</a></li>
    <li><a>Cigándi Járási Hivatal</a></li>
    <li><a>ITS projekt</a></li>
    <li><a>Település üzemeltetés</a></li>
    <li><a>Művészeti csoportok</a></li>
    <li><a>ÁNYK nyomtatványok</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```